# Android: java.net.DatagramSocket.bind: Invalid Argument Exception

Tags: java, android, bind, arguments

Background: I'm writing a simple UDP application to ping a beta server I manage every minute or so to tell me it is still up and running (I can't enable ping on the server for those that are wondering).  I plan to run this on my phone to warn me when the server is no longer responding.

I'm trying to use the seemingly simple java.net.DatagramSocket as such:

```
    try
    {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.bind(null);
    } 
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        throw e;
    }
```

Let me also say that I have enabled the Internet permissions through the android manifest and if I remove the uses clause to do so, I get a permissions error so I'm sure that is working OK.  When I download this code to an Android Virtual Device (AVD) and execute it, on the call to bind() I am presented with this exception:

03-17 19:07:39.401: INFO/System.out(338): java.net.BindException: Invalid argument

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#bind%28java.net.SocketAddress%29) documentation, the null argument is correct:

> public void bind (SocketAddress localAddr)
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> Binds this socket to the local address and port specified by localAddr. **If this value is   null any free port on a valid local address is used**.

But not trusting documentation, I decided to enumerate the IP addresses on my device like this:

```
    ArrayList<NetworkInterface>  allInterfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
    
    NetworkInterface eth = allInterfaces.get(0);
                
    InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(eth.getInetAddresses().nextElement(), port);
    
    try
    {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.bind(addr);
    } 
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        throw e;
    }
```

When I step through the code, it works great and I can see the two IP address on the AVD but I get the exact same exception on the bind() call.  Does anybody out there see what i might be missing?  I will continue to research and hopefully post a solution to my own problem, but I am hoping somebody out there will be able to shortcut this for me.

Comment: port number? is it within valid range?

Comment: try with different port number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Edited: if you saw my previous response I made the classic debugging mistake of changing two variable in one test and it was the other one that solved my problem.]

I found the problem.  It is the way I'm declaring the DatagramSocket that appears to cause problems.  If I use a DatagramChannel to open the DatagramSocket in the following way then the bind() call is successful.

```
      DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
      DatagramSocket socket = channel.socket();
```

Comment: new DatagramSocket(null);

Answer (score 3):

I've stumbled across this problem either and have found the cause: if you call the parameterless constructor `new DatagramSocket()`, this creates "a UDP datagram socket **which is bound to any available port** on the local host using a wildcard address" (as per the API docs). So this actually means, the Socket is already bound. My "fix" for this is as follows:

```
        SocketAddress socketAddress = new SocketAddress(yourInetAddress, yourPort);
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(null);
        serverSocket.bind(socketAddress);
```

This explicitly creates an unbound Socket (through the `DatagramSocket (SocketAddress localAddr)` constructor), making it possible to bind the Socket in turn.

This is probably the more elegant solution than creating an unnecessary channel.

P.S.: Strangely enough, this is where `DatagramSocket` differs from a TCP `ServerSocket`: the parameterless constructor of the latter will create an unbound ServerSocket, not triggering this problem.