# Which Socket API to use android.net or java.net for UDP Communication in Android?

Tags: java, android, network-programming, udp

I need UDP Communication between my device and/or an another android device / iPhone / Server etc.

While exploring the android developer site I found that their are two packages java.net (plain Java Classes) and android.net(Looks like they are android specific implementations). Which set of classes I should use so that I don't get any problem while connecting to other devices. Which is the most efficient way to provide UDP socket communication in Android. I saw [Android UDP Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904820/android-udp-communication) but that also looks incomplete.

Comment: There are no UDP communications-related classes in `android.net` AFAIK.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, you can add your comment as answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard `java.net.UserDatagramSocket/Packet`. Here is the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) and [example](http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/).

Answer (score 1):

For UDP, Android relies on java.net packages it self. You should use Java.